# How to use twig function inside another module or plugin?

Tags: plugins, modules, twigextension

How to use twig function extensions inside another module or plugin?

Say I created `filterCats()` twig function and it is already available in `twig`
Is it possible to use it inside a module or plugin? How?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. If the module/plugin implementing the Twig function is correctly installed, that function will automatically be available anywhere Twig is rendered.